# Property vs RACSignal

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I just started with ReactiveCocoa (and FRP for that matter) and every time I start refactoring my code to be more RAC-based, I ask myself: when should I create a property or a RACSignal?

For example, if I have a ViewModel that does some checking to see if a button can be enabled or not, should I do this:

```
dynamic var ready: NSNumber //Bool
```

Or this:

```
var ready: RACSignal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start writing more RAC-based code, then I would *highly* encourage you to use a `RACSignal` instead of a value property, for two reasons:

1. `RACSignal` use on view models is arguably more idiomatic (i.e.: a more "RAC" way of doing things).
2. Not having access to the property value at any given time will force you to think in terms of FRP, helping you learn RAC faster.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Will follow your advice. Btw, thank you for all your articles on RAC, they motivated me to dig deeper in the framework.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on your use case. If it's a continuous stream of events, it might make sense to use the `RACSignal` approach. if it's a one time thing, a `Bool` could suit you.

Comment: That makes sense - I was thinking also that if the property/signal will be subscribed by more than one object, it makes sense for it to be a RACSignal, avoiding the creation of multiple signals.

Comment: you can still observe a property without the use of explicitly making it a signal: `RACObserve()`. Be careful with multiple subscribers tho: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#side-effects-occur-for-each-subscription

Comment: But isn't RACObserve just a simpler way to create a RACSignal? https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#introduction

Comment: It will create a `RACSignal` out of a property yes.